# ModuleNotFoundError error from .pyd file

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I had to to transform a module from .py to .pyd. I did it with Cython. I tested after the project, and everything worked fine. When I created a build with cx_Freeze, that .pyd module created problems. I can't understand why after building I get this `ModuleNotFoundError`.

```
 File "tooth_comp.pyx", line 13, in int
src.graphics_dental_components.tooth_comp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphics_utils.effects'
```

My setup script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

packages = []
excludes = []
include_files = ["assets", "views"]

build_exe_options = {"packages": packages, "excludes": excludes, "include_files": include_files}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "MyApp",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error message is because the application cannot find the extension.

Try adding `graphics_utils.effects` to the `packages` list then try recompiling.

If that does not work you could also try coping the module in the build folder manually.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much !

Comment: @EugeniuZnagovan Very pleased it did.  Cx_Freeze is a pain to use but adding the missing thing in `include_files` or `packages` generally does the trick. : )